# Fighting in the dark

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When a PC is fighting in the dark and rolls a natural 20 is there still a 50% chance of a miss? The rules say the following about fighting in the [dark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/environmental-rules#TOC-Darkness):

> All opponents have total concealment from a blinded creature, so the blinded creature has a 50% miss chance in combat.

But the rules also say the following for a [Natural 20](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Natural-20):

> A natural 20 (the d20 comes up 20) is always a hit. A natural 20 is also a Critical Threat—a possible critical hit.

So if I roll a 20 on the die is a percentage roll required?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Yes

The rules for [Concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment) describe the order of operations for miss chance thusly:

> Concealment gives the subject of a successful attack a 20% chance that the attacker missed because of the concealment. Make the attack normally—**if the attacker hits, the defender must make a miss chance d% roll to avoid being struck.** Multiple concealment conditions do not stack. *(emphasis mine)*

We can see from this that the miss chance is *only* ever rolled when the attack roll already indicates a hit. Therefore, the process that occurs when a natural 20 is rolled is:

1. Attacker rolls 20.
2. Attacker rolls to confirm Critical Threat.
3. Defender rolls for miss chance.

However, this ordering is not strictly necessary, since the attack and miss chance die rolls are all independent. If you don't enjoy raining on your players' parades when they roll natural 20s, I suggest rolling for miss chance before the attack roll, rather than after.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea to roll d100 % miss chances before d20 hit rolls, I'm going to enforce it.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. There was just the confusion of the wording that a nat 20 is an automatic hit. This makes more sense now.